# Random distribution like discrete_distribution<float>

Tags: c++, distribution

discrete_distribution can only be used with integer types, is there something similar for floats?

I want to write something like

```
distribution<float> myDistribution = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2};

int index = myDistribution(generator);
```

It is important that the random number generation is O(log(N)).

Comment: Scale by using integers and then divide the output.   eg. (distribute_over{1, 2, 5, 2}) / 10.0 --> output.  (Remember that float/double is not precise).

Comment: I thought about that but I think it will only work well for simple cases, my floats can become very small and the distribution has to be accurate.

Comment: I don't understand your snippet of code. Because, in your example, you generate `int`. Is it what you want?

Comment: I want to create an int, but the weights have to be floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) is the following:

```
template< class IntType = int >
class discrete_distribution;
```

As explained:

> **IntType** - The result type generated by the generator. The effect is undefined if this is not one of `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

So the result type should be an integer. But it is not the case for the weights, who can be floating point numbers. Indeed, the signature of one of the [constructor of this class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution) is:

```
discrete_distribution( std::initializer_list<double> weights );
```

Therefore, we can use floating point numbers as weights:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::discrete_distribution<int> myDistribution = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2};

    std::map<int, int> m;

    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[myDistribution(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is the following:

```
0 generated 1023 times
1 generated 1969 times
2 generated 5005 times
3 generated 2003 times
```

We can see the weights indicated in the `std::initializer_list` are respected.

Comment: I feel sorry for this question now, I misunderstood the class, thinking that the template argument was the type of the weights. A big thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather find the common multiple that makes all of them ints and use that in `discrete_distribution`.

Alternatively, you can use `piecewise_constant_distribution` if you really need. The weights will be your floats and the intervals are then just unit intervals.

```
std::vector<double> i{0.0,  1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
std::vector<double> w{0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2};

std::piecewise_constant_distribution<> d(i.begin(), i.end(), w.begin());
```

(and then cast the result to int by flooring)

However, I do not think the standard guarantees complexity on either generator.

Comment: Sounds like this will do the trick. According to cppreference it's also amortized constant time.